# In Laravel hasMany relationship How to use with and where?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, where-clause, has-many

### In Job model :

public function jobApplications() 
 {
return $this->hasMany(JobApplication::class, 'job_id');
}

### In JobApplication Model

public function jobs() 
{
return $this->belongsTo(Job::class, 'job_id');
}

### In job_applications migration

$table->id();
$table->foreignId("job_id")->constrained("jobs");
$table->foreignId("user_id")->constrained("users");
$table->text('remarks')->nullable();
$table->unsignedInteger('status')->default(1);

**I need to get all jobs and its job applications where job_applications.status = (user input status) and job_applications.user_id =authenticated users id. How can i get that?**
Below is the syntax i tried, which returned undefined variable status

$jobs = Job::where('status',1);
$status =$request->status;

if($status){
$jobs = $jobs->whereHas('jobApplications', function($q){
$q->where('status',$status);
$q->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id);
});
return $jobs->get();
Can any one sugest a solution?

Comment: Unrelated, but wouldn't it make more sense if JobApplication had the method `public function job()` as it's a belongsTo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use closer the variabl that is defined outside the closer is not accessible. so you should use it. Like this.

```
if($status){
   $jobs = $jobs->whereHas('jobApplications', function($q) use($status){
    $q->where('status',$status);
   $q->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id);
  });
```

This will remove the error undefined veriable $status.

Answer (score 0):

to use an external variable in closure method you need to pass that variable into method using "use" keyword like

```
if($status){
   $jobs = $jobs->whereHas('jobApplications', function($q) use ($status) {
   $q->where('status',$status);
   $q->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id);
});}
return $jobs->get();
```

Comment: Thanks bro!! There is also a small correction,you  forgot to close closure for " if ". so it will be like..
if($status){
                $jobs = $jobs->whereHas('jobApplications', function($q) use($status){
                    $q->where('status',$status);
                    $q->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id);
                });
            }
            return $jobs->get();

Comment: yes Vishnu you're right I forgot that closing braces but my main theme was to correct actual issue of undefined variable that is being only corrected using 'use' keyword

Comment: ok. and what should i do if jobApplications have another relation users() and i want to get users whose  name = $request->name. for example, whereHas('jobApplications.users'). I dont know if the syntax is correct.

Comment: you can use `with` in Laravel relationships to get related records